# Looking for design help

Tags: design-patterns

I have this scenario in most of the WindowsForms having grids
I have a sequence of code which is similar -
AddNewRow(in grid),CreateNewEntity,notifyUser,few other steps
Now, I want to use a template kind of pattern.But,my issue is with CreateEntity method since sometimes it is passed a parameter which is different depending on the type of object being created.Should I make createentity accept an "object" type,and cast when the parameter is to be used.What other way can I tackle this design issue? Also,CreateEntity returns the object being created.

Actually, my scenario has MVP pattern.Now,most of the interaction between presenter and view in most forms is the same - user clicks add,a new row is added with some default values for the entity(to show in the grid),n some other common stuff

Comment: Any chance at all you could post a little more information?  Not enough context to give a good suggestion.   Maybe a couple sample code blocks?  Or the types of objects you will be managing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a templated function?  This probably isn't a good example, but it's hard to imagine what a good example would be without more specific information:

```
interface IInitializable
{
   void Initialize(string input);
}

public T CreateNewEntity<T>(T inputObject, string otherData) where T : IInitializable
{
   inputObject.Initialize(otherData);
   return inputObject;
}
```

Comment: this might be the solution.will try it out.Actually, my scenario has MVP pattern.Now,most of the interaction between presenterand view in most forms is same - user clicks add,a new row is added with some default values for the entity(to show in the grid),n some other common stuff.